# finding the center of round rectangle in java game programming

Tags: java, user-interface, graphics

Is there any way to find the center of the round rectangle? And keeping in mind that the round rectangle changes its co-ordinates using a key listener.

`a= new RoundRectangle(10,10,10,10,10,10)`

Comment: What is actually a round rectangle? Anyway, a solution is possible if your geometric object can be described by an equation or a system of equations.

Comment: OP probably means a rounded rectangle, where we have rounded edges?

Comment: round rectangle = circle :-D

Comment: There is no RoundRectangle class in the standard java libs. There is a RoundRectangle2D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `getCenterX()` and `getCenterY()` methods inherited from `RectangularShape` class.

Here is the [api documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/RectangularShape.html#getCenterX%28%29).

Comment: There is no such methods inherited roundrectangle class.

Comment: Glad to know it helped.

Answer (score 0):

For a rectangle (unless its mode is set differently, like CENTERMODE) we have an x, y and size value.

To get the center you could simply take the

```
x + size/2
```

to get the x co-ordinate and

```
y + size/2
```

for the y co-ordinate.